# On focusing back to Username text field clears the previously entered data

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-tv

I am using **MiBox3** with **Android 6.0.1**

I've a scenarios:

I am loading a login page(third party, Let's say facebook.com) into webview of my androidTv app.
Login screen has 2 text boxes, 1 is of type **text** to enter the user name and second one is of type **password** to enter password.
Suppose user enters the username in *user name* textbox and then move to *password* text and then if user tries to navigate back to *user name* textbox it is clearing the previously entered data. but the same behavior is not seen with *password* text box.

What i am doing is, i am just initializing android webview and the loading the URL using *WebView.loadURL()* function.

This issue is seen only with **Leanback Keyboard** and if **Google Indic Keyboard** is used, this issue is not seen in same hardware with other keyboards.

Do we have any fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried android tv emulator?

Comment: Actually no. Issue is fully reproducible in hardware at my desk so did not try this in emulator and was trying to debug this..
Just one question, emulator's keyboard and actual hardware's keyboard implementation is same?

Comment: keyboard is always software implementation in Android TV.

Comment: so you mean to say we can change this behavior? Can you please describe a little bit more on how can we do it?
or you can lead me to a path where i should check and what should i check?

Comment: Run your app on tv emulator.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately my laptop is not compatible to run emulator.. :/  Any other suggestion?